# How can I copy files from a Google Cloud Compute Server to my local machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to download all of the server files from Google Cloud Compute (running Linux Debian). I'm extremely unfamiliar with SSH and Google Cloud Compute as a whole. I'd prefer either copying all of the files (similar to a git pull request) or creating a zip and downloading. In short I need to copy all of the files on the remove Google Cloud server to my local machine.

Comment: maybe this can give you another option

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27792823/2406499

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp):

```
gcloud compute scp 
  [[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC [[[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC …]
  [[USER@]INSTANCE:]DEST
  [--compress] [--dry-run] [--force-key-file-overwrite]
  [--plain] [--port=PORT] [--recurse] [--scp-flag=SCP_FLAG]
  [--ssh-key-file=SSH_KEY_FILE]
  [--strict-host-key-checking=STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING]
  [--zone=ZONE]
  [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
  [-h]
```

e.g.,

```
$ gcloud compute scp \
    my-instance-1:~/file-1 \
    my-instance-2:~/file-2 \
    ~/my-destination \
    --zone us-central2-a
```

As an alternative, you can also use (non-`gcloud`) `sftp` or `scp`; see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22203728/3618671) for details on the command line arguments you need to specify, which I'll quote here for simplicity:

```
sftp -o IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine user@host
```

To use any other SFTP tool, similarly provide to it the path to the SSH private key and it will be able to connect to the instance. However, in the case of `gcloud`, it can resolve the hostname to the public IP themselves; for all other tools, you'll need to find the IP manually and specify the IP address directly.

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to remove files and then delete them as they are copied?

Comment: @MCllorf — I'm not sure I follow what you're asking, can you please open another question with more details and the use case or goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I definitely could have phrased that better. My aim was to copy the file to somewhere else, and then delete the original so it doesn't take up unnecessary space. I've already figured it out though :) thanks!

Answer (score 5):

(`gcloud compute copy-files` is deprecated now, hence `gcloud compute scp` is recommended)

Use `gcloud compute scp` as follows:

```
gcloud compute scp [[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC [[[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC …]
[[USER@]INSTANCE:]DEST [--compress] [--dry-run] [--force-key-file-overwrite]
[--plain] [--port=PORT] [--recurse] [--scp-flag=SCP_FLAG] 
[--ssh-key-file=SSH_KEY_FILE] [--strict-host-key-checking=STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING]
[--zone=ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

For example:

```
$ gcloud compute scp example-instance:~/REMOTE-DIR ~/LOCAL-DIR \
      --zone us-central1-a
```

If the zone is already set (using `gcloud config set compute/zone ZONE` or through the environment variable, then you dont need to specify the zone above)

Also, `gcloud compute scp` does not copy recursively by default. We need to use the `--recurse` flag for it.

See the detailed documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use SFTP (google used Filezilla in their docs). I am not too good with CLI and hence like the GUI options Filezilla and other provides.

Here are the steps at a high level:

1. Install and run the gcloud SDK (`$ gcloud init`)
2. Generate SSH key (`$ gcloud compute ssh`)
3. Setup the FTP client (install and add the key file)
4. Connect to the VM using the SFTP client

And here is [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/transfer-files?hl=en) from Google.

Also, I have recorded this, it might be helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ssfE6ODpak

Answer (score 1):

If you connect to the instance via web-based terminal that Google Cloud Console provides, you can click on the cog in the upper right corner and select "Download file", then enter the full path to the file and it will be downloaded via browser. Same thing goes for uploading.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Syntax :

```
gcloud compute scp <UserName>@<ServerName/InstanceName>:~/<FilePathFromInstance> <LocalSystemFilePath>
```