# Google Compute Engine - SSH or RSYNC without a Password

Tags: ssh, passwords, rsync, google-compute-engine

I have several Google Compute Engine (GCE) instances up and running. I have a few scripts that pull information (log files, etc) from these instances, and a few others that push up files. I would like to automate more of this, but every time I connect to a compute engine instance I need to enter my password.

How do I setup rsync or ssh so I do not need a passoword, or alternatively, how do I feed my password into those programs?

*Note that this was [originally posted to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986578/google-compute-engine-ssh-or-rsync-without-a-password) but then moved over here.*

Comment: Is GCE special somehow? There are _quite_ a few [existing posts](http://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password) talking about passwordless SSH connections using public-key authentication.

Answer (score 1):

GCE ssh uses public key authentication, not passwords, so you have the following options:

1. use [`gcloud compute copy-files`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#copyfiles) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23699894/3618671). This is likely easier as it will allow you to specify projects and host names symbolically, as the IP addresses may change.
2. use `sftp` as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/790228/321938), namely:

   ```
   sftp -o IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine user@host
   ```
3. use `ssh` but with a full path to the key file registered with GCE. This command is printed out when you run `gcloud compute ssh <instance>` so you can just copy-paste it and use it later. It should resemble the following:

   ```
   ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine \
       -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
       -o CheckHostIP=no \
       -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
       USER@IP_ADDRESS
   ```

   Note that here you will have to use exact IP addresses here, so consider either using static IP addresses or DNS to create a constant name for possibly-varying IP addresses (if you're using dynamic IPs).

   You can read more in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#standardssh).